# How to Select/find all Unweighted Bones on an armature?

Tags: rigging, edit-mode

I'm working with Blender to create models for use in Unreal engine, and UE shows bones that do not have vertices weighted against them as greyed out. Is there a similar feature in Blender? I want to delete ALL bones that don't have any weights on them, and a way to easily select all of them would be greatly appreciated

Picture from UE:
[image]